# NativeScript - does not run on iOS device with firebase plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, nativescript, provisioning-profile

It is impossible to run iOS Application written in NativeScrip on real device. I tried everything. Application works on iOS Symulator and Android Emulator but when I connect iOS device and run `ins run ios` a get an error

> ** EXPORT SUCCEEDED **
>
> Project successfully built.
>
> Installing...
>
> Unable to apply changes on device: XXXXX. Error is: Failed to install
>
> on device with identifier: XXXXX
>   Error is: Could not install application.

I went to `platforms/ios` and run generated Xcode project. Then I build it and try to run. The error appeared:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I have set proper `Team` and `Provision Profile`.

I don't know how to fix that. I have only an idea. I have installed firebase-plugin which needs keychain_sharing maybe it is a problem with `Entitlements`.

My `package.json`

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescrip.awsomename",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.1.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.2.0-2017-8-25-1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~4.2.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^4.0.6",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.4.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
    "babel-types": "6.26.0",
    "babylon": "6.18.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

My `build.cconfig` from `AppResorces/iOS`

```
// You can add custom settings here
// for example you can uncomment the following line to force distribution code signing
// CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Distribution 
// To build for device with Xcode 8 you need to specify your development team. More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html
// DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = YOUR_TEAM_ID;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;

DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = [HERE I HAVE SET MY DEV TEAM ID];
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = swapmobile/swapmobile.entitlements
```

I use Xcode 8.3.2

## EDIT

After `tns plugin remove nativescript-plugin-firebase` application starts to work. The problem is with firebase plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the entitlements file given in the readme [see issue #420](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/420) works for the simulator but then device builds result in entitlement errors unless those entitlements are removed. The following *.entitlements file works for both device and simulator builds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
  <array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.Company.Product</string>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note - replace "com.Company.Product" with your bundle identifier.

This is the entitlements entry that Xcode puts in when you enable "Keychain Sharing" in the project's capabilities. Additional details can be found in the Apple documentation [Keychain Services Programming Guide - Access Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-SW1) which state that:

> Xcode automatically adds the application-identifier entitlement to every app during code signing. This string is formed as the team identifier plus the bundle identifier.

Device builds work without specifying the entitlement because they are always signed and given the above entitlement. Unsigned simulator builds need to be explicitly given this entitlement.